# Fatal error: Call to undefined function title_taxonomy_allowed_values()

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, features

I am attempting to incorporate a feature I created which uses a content type and taxonomy terms, among other things. I had to re-add the taxonomy terms for the vocabulary which was included in the feature, however, both before and after adding the terms, I received the following error once I tried to add the content type on a new website:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   title_taxonomy_allowed_values() in
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/example/docroot/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module
>   on line 1496

Any help to troubleshoot this issue is greatly appreciated.

Drupal 7.54
Local Dev using AMPPS

Comment: See [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2293347) and [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2505505). Looks like if you export a module from a website which has [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module enabled, and try to import it to a site without that module, this ugly error creeps its head. You need to refer to the above attached issues and try their suggested fixes/patches.

Comment: #5 from the second link worked for me in all cases except one. I noticed that quiz and other content types on the new site have "title" for the machine readable name instead of "title_field" Because I have featurized configurations and implemented them, it's giving me this error when I try to add a quiz: `EntityFieldQueryException: Unknown field: title_field in EntityFieldQuery->fieldOrderBy() (line 954 of /includes/entity.inc).` . It doesn't complain about other content types that were part of the feature, however, even though the title machine name is also different..